# Can anyone help my identify this card game

Tags: identify-this-game, billionaire

It's a game about capitalism and I cannot remember it's name for the life of me
[image: picture of le card]

Answer (score 28):

The card game [Pit](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/140/pit) had a version that was released under the name "Billionaire" circa 1984, which is where your card comes from. [This image](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/image/94590/pit) contains the full set of cards including the one you showed.